# How do I Retrieve an Object Instance with Django RetrieveModelMixin

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to retrieve and objects instance with this call:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/get-factor/?code=ABC
```

I have the following:

### models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Factor(models.Model):
    
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

### serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Factor

class GetFactorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Factor
        fields = ('value',)
        lookup_field = 'code'
```

### urls.py in factors app

```
from django.urls import path, include
from factors import views 
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('get-factor', views.RetrieveFactor)

urlpatterns = [

    path('', include(router.urls)),

]
```

### urls.py in project

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include 



urlpatterns = [

   
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('api/', include('factors.urls')),
]
```

### views.py

```
from .models import Factor

#api
from .serializers import GetFactorSerializer
from rest_framework import mixins
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet

class RetrieveFactor(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Factor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GetFactorSerializer
    lookup_field = 'code'
```

### using postman with this call:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/get-factor/?code=ABC
```

results in a

```
Page not found (404)
```

the routes it shows are:

```
api/ ^get-factor/(?P<code>[^/.]+)/$ [name='factor-detail']
api/ ^get-factor/(?P<code>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='factor-detail']
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: use ***`http://localhost:8000/api/get-factor/ABC/`***

Comment: thank you.  This was the issue.  Can you point me to a resource that explains why this works versus the ? parameter I was using?